# Firebase Functions error: .once is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to deploy a simple function to Firebase, but I am having some difficulties. Every time I try to use .once on a reference Firebase tells me that it is not a function. Here is my code

```
exports.testFunction = functions.database.ref('/Rooms/{firstID}/{pushId}/On').onWrite(event => {
  const value = event.data.val();
  var ref = functions.database.ref(roomNum);
  return ref.once('value').then(snapshot => {
    console.log(snapshot.numChildren);
    return true;
  }); });
```

I have also tried the following:

```
firebaseRef.once('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.numChildren);
});
```

Nothing seems to work. Does anyone know of a fix or a different way of getting the number of children from a ref/snapshot?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`functions.database.ref` is a different object than the one you're used to using on the client. It's sole purpose is to listen for writes using it's only function, `onWrite`.

You can obtain your intended ref thru the `event` parameter.

`var ref = event.data.ref`

This is a reference to the path you specified in `onWrite`.

If you want the root reference:

`var rootRef = event.data.ref.root`

Further reading: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database

Comment: Yep, that makes total sense. Thank you.