# How do i reference Firebase's realtime database from within a cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In a Firebase Cloud function i am attempting to retrieve data from my Realtime Database and write an update to it as well. This is where i am having trouble.

The function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
...

api.post('/messages/add', (request: any, response: any) => {

  const dbRef:any = functions.database.ref(`count/${request.body.chatRoomId}`);

  dbRef.once('value').then((snapshot:any) => {
      let messageCount:number = (snapshot.val() && snapshot.val().messages) || 0;
      messageCount = Number(messageCount + 1);
      dbRef.update({
        messages: messageCount,
        updated: admin.database().database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
      });
  });

});
```

When i call this function from the client, in the firebase cloud console logs, i am seeing the following error:

```
TypeError: dbRef.once is not a function
```

I have tried referencing the database in each of the following ways, all of which fail:

```
functions.database.ref(`count/${request.body.chatRoomId}`).once('value').then((snapshot)) =>

functions.database.ref(`count/${request.body.chatRoomId}`).once('value', (snapshot) =>

admin.database().ref(`count/${request.body.chatRoomId}`).once('value').then((snapshot)) =>

admin.database().ref(`count/${request.body.chatRoomId}`).once('value', (snapshot) =>
```

When attempting the reference using the Admin SDK via `admin.database()` i get a different error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ServerValue' of undefined
    at dbRef.once.then
```

Lastly, i can confirm that the value for `${request.body.chatRoomId}` is resolving correctly, i had tested this by printing its value to the console.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44574297/2934896) shows how to reference the realtime database from the 'event' response within a realtime database listener like `onWrite()` for example, however my function is not triggered by realtime database changes, but rather is an endpoint reachable from the client.

**UPDATE**

**The answer proposed by Doug Stevenson below is correct** *but there was also an additional error due to attempting to write a timestamp incorrectly to a field that i had initially excluded which was causing my function to fail despite having tried his solution, thus I have updated the code to reflect this.*

First, the answer is to reference the Realtime Database with `admin.database()`

Second, even though i had tried this, i was still seeing an error, but the error was due to attempting to set a timestamp incorrectly. Thanks to **Frank van Puffelen** for pointing this out.

This: `admin.database().database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

Needs to be: `admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

And with that it works.

Comment: When posting questions about code, it's very helpful if you provide a MCVE, not just an approximation of the code.  We need to see exactly what you're doing, and be able to reproduce it exactly as you're seeing it.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You are correct, i was trying to keep things simple and in doing so, i missed the line causing the problem all together. Updating now to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making the mistake of trying to use the functions SDK to query the database.  This is not actually creating a database reference:

```
functions.database.ref(`count/${request.body.chatRoomId}`);
```

The functions SDK is just used for declaring and configuring Cloud Functions.

What you should be doing instead is using the Admin SDK to create a reference, then query it:

```
admin.database().ref(...).once(...)
```

You also need to initialize the Admin SDK exactly once before you use it:

```
admin.initializeApp();
```

Comment: If you look further down in my question, i did attempt to reference the database with the admin SDK via `admin.database()` which results in the same error noted. I am initializing the application as well at the start of my index.ts via `admin.initializeApp();`  ill update the question.

Comment: CORRECTION: when using the admin SDK the error is different. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ServerValue' of undefined
    at dbRef.once.then (/srv/lib/index.js:476:51)` i will update to reflect this.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't use `ServerValue`, but my guess is that you're using the wrong syntax. It should look like `admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Ah! i had removed several fields from the code in an attempt to keep things short ... in addition to the one field i noted, i was also attempting to write additional fields including a timestamp to the database via `updated: admin.database().database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` i will try removing this field all together to see what happens

Comment: I realize thank you's are discouraged, but if you both had not taken the time to respond, i might not have solved this, so thank you. I will update the post to reflect this and mark this as the answer.